# How to calculate 7 day sums but differentiate amongst groups

Tags: r

In the case that I am trying to tackle I have the States of Germany, dates and new cases of COVID per day (for different age groups) in a data frame. Looks similar to this:

| State | Date | Cases | Age bracket |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bavaria | 01-01-2021 | 1 | 14-29 |
| Bavaria | 01-01-2021 | 5 | 30-50 |
| Bavaria | 02-01-2021 | 9 | 14-29 |
| Bavaria | 02-01-2021 | 10 | 30-50 |
| Sachsen | 01-01-2021 | 12 | 14-29 |
| Sachsen | 01-01-2021 | 3 | 30-50 |
| Sachsen | 02-01-2021 | 13 | 14-29 |
| Sachsen | 02-01-2021 | 6 | 30-50 |

I am trying to calculate the seven days incidence and I found this piece of code:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(group = cut(date_entered, '7 days')) %>%
  summarise(date_range = paste(min(date_entered), min(date_entered) + 6, sep = '-'), 
            sum_new = sum(new)) %>%
  select(-group)
```

From this answer on a similar question: [find the sum after every seventh day but with missing days in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68448586/find-the-sum-after-every-seventh-day-but-with-missing-days-in-r)

The output however is that the seven day incidence is calculated, but disregarding from which State the cases come from. Therefore, I am wondering if there is a way to calculate the seven day incidence, but for each State separetely.

Comment: Add state and age bracket to the group_by

Comment: Indeed adding this solved it for me:

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(State, group = cut(date_entered, '7 days')) %>%
  summarise(date_range = paste(min(date_entered), min(date_entered) + 6, sep = '-'), 
            sum_new = sum(new)) %>%
  select(-group)